# Azure ARM template using utcNow not working properly

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

Have tried to create an Azure ARM Template with a parameter that should have a datetime default value.
This is how I am using it:

```
"endTime": {
  "type": "string",
  "defaultValue": "[dateTimeAdd(utcNow('u'), 'PT1H', 'yyyy-MM-dd THH:mm:ss zzzz')]",
  "metadata": {
    "description": "The finishing date of the Lab. Ex: 2019-09-23T09:00:00"
  }
}
```

The parameter when its executed appears like text:

```
[dateTimeAdd(utcNow('u'), 'PT1H', 'yyyy-MM-dd THH:mm:ss zzzz')]
```

Anyone knows what the issue might be? I am executing the ARM template on Dev/Test Labs.

Comment: Basically the function is not evaluated when the parameters are requested for input... it’s only evaluated once you deploy the template. I wanted the function to set the default value with the evaluated value instead of the expression.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the function is not evaluated when the parameters are requested for input... it’s only evaluated once you deploy the template.
I wanted the function to set the default value with the evaluated value instead of the expression.